# How to import a text file on AWS S3 into pandas without writing to disk

Tags: python, pandas, heroku, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a text file saved on S3 which is a tab delimited table. I want to load it into pandas but cannot save it first because I am running on a heroku server. Here is what I have so far.

```
import io
import boto3
import os
import pandas as pd

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "xxxxxxxx"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "xxxxxxxx"

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="my_bucket",Key="filename.txt")
file = response["Body"]


pd.read_csv(file, header=14, delimiter="\t", low_memory=False)
```

the error is

```
OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

How do I convert the response body into a format pandas will accept?

```
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file), header=14, delimiter="\t", low_memory=False)

returns

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not StreamingBody

pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file), header=14, delimiter="\t", low_memory=False)

returns

TypeError: 'StreamingBody' does not support the buffer interface
```

UPDATE - Using the following worked

```
file = response["Body"].read()
```

and

```
pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file), header=14, delimiter="\t", low_memory=False)
```

Comment: try it this way: `io.BytesIO(file)` or `io.StringIO(file)` instead of `file` in the `read_csv()` call

Comment: You could use `io.StringIO` as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34447506/5276797).

Comment: Neither of these suggestions worked. You can see the errors in my post edit.

Comment: The UPDATE part worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 169):

`pandas` uses `boto` for `read_csv`, so you should be able to:

```
import boto
data = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket....csv')
```

If you need `boto3` because you are on `python3.4+`, you can

```
import boto3
import io
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='key')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

Since [version 0.20.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#s3-file-handling) `pandas` uses `s3fs`, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777553/2339228).

Comment: Is there a way to use a URL without making it public to everyone? The file needs to stay private.

Comment: The `boto3` docs show how to configure authentication so that you can access private files as well: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html

Comment: It is throwing  NoCredentialsError. How do I set s3 credentials tl it? I am new to python and boto

Comment: I found that I had to do the following on the last example with boto3: 

    `df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), encoding='utf8')`

Comment: This answer is **out of date**.  Please see [Wesams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777553/974555).

Comment: @Stefan Thank you so much, I've been looking for days on how to simply read a csv from S3 into pandas dataframe and this worked for me! (using Python 3.6)

Answer (score 122):

Now [pandas can handle S3 URLs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#reading-remote-files).  You could simply do:

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

df = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket-name/file.csv')
```

[You need to install `s3fs`](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) if you don't have it.  `pip install s3fs`

#### Authentication

If your S3 bucket is private and requires authentication, you have two options:

1- Add access credentials to your [`~/.aws/credentials` config file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html)

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

Or

2- Set the following [environment variables](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials) with their proper values:

- `aws_access_key_id`
- `aws_secret_access_key`
- `aws_session_token`

Comment: Beautiful. Works in python3.

Comment: how about authentication ..?

Comment: @JamesWierzba , I added more details on authentication to my answer above.

Comment: When dealing with multiple aws profiles, how can you select which profile should be used? s3fs has the profile_name option, but I'm not sure how that works with pandas.

Comment: This be the way to go. Not sure why *pandas* doesn't require and then import *s3fs* though?

Comment: @IvoMerchiers have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: @IanS Not really, currently, I first open the file object with s3fs (using the specified profile) and then I read it with pandas, like they do here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16692

Comment: > When dealing with multiple aws profiles

It will be supported as of 1.2.0
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/df32e83f36bf485be803be2b87d23135be30540a/pandas/io/parsers.py#L358
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35381

`pd.read_csv('s3://hoge/piyo', storage_options={'aws_access_key_id': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'aws_secret_access_key': 'yyyyyyyyyy'})`

Answer (score 22):

This is now supported in latest pandas. See

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#reading-remote-files

eg.,

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://pandas-test/tips.csv')
```

Comment: Remember 'S3 URLs are handled as well but require installing the S3Fs library'

Comment: what about authenticating

Comment: url with auth may be difficult unless, the url is exposed as public, not sure if simple/basic http auth will work,

Comment: Regarding authentication, you need to set the `credentials` file in your machine, i.e. you need to set up your AWS CLI.

Answer (score 20):

For python 3.6+ Amazon now have a really nice library to use Pandas with their services, called [awswrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler).

```
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3


# Boto3 session
session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='XXXX', 
                                aws_secret_access_key='XXXX')

# Awswrangler pass forward all pd.read_csv() function args
df = wr.s3.read_csv(path='s3://bucket/path/',
                    boto3_session=session,
                    skiprows=2,
                    sep=';',
                    decimal=',',
                    na_values=['--'])
```

To install awswrangler: `pip install awswrangler`

Comment: If you're going to be using AWS/Python/Pandas/Glue/etc... AWS Wrangler is your new best friend.

Answer (score 13):

With [s3fs](http://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it can be done as follow:

```
import s3fs
import pandas as pd
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

# CSV
with fs.open('mybucket/path/to/object/foo.pkl') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)

# Pickle
with fs.open('mybucket/path/to/object/foo.pkl') as f:
    df = pd.read_pickle(f)
```

Comment: I think with s3fs you can even write `df = pd.read_csv('s3://mybucket/path/to/object/foo.pkl')`

Comment: @louis_guitton this seems to work with pd-read_csv but not with read_pickle

Answer (score 3):

Since the files can be too large, it is not wise to load them in the dataframe altogether. Hence, read line by line and save it in the dataframe. Yes, we can also provide the chunk size in the read_csv but then we have to maintain the number of rows read.

Hence, I came up with this engineering:

```
def create_file_object_for_streaming(self):
        print("creating file object for streaming")
        self.file_object = self.bucket.Object(key=self.package_s3_key)
        print("File object is: " + str(self.file_object))
        print("Object file created.")
        return self.file_object

for row in codecs.getreader(self.encoding)(self.response[u'Body']).readlines():
            row_string = StringIO(row)
            df = pd.read_csv(row_string, sep=",")
```

I also delete the df once work is done.
`del df`

Answer (score 2):

For text files, you can use below code with pipe-delimited file for example :-

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', use_ssl=False)
bucket = #
prefix = #
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=prefix+ filename)
df = pd.read_fwf((io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())) , encoding= 'unicode_escape', delimiter='|', error_bad_lines=False,header=None, dtype=str)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="test")

os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = session.get_credentials().access_key
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = session.get_credentials().secret_key
```

So this way you can use any profile (AWS account) you have stored in  ~/.aws/credentials

```
df = pd.read_csv("s3://xxxx.csv")
```

Comment: this did not work for me without also adding `import s3fs`

Answer (score 0):

An option is to convert the csv to json via `df.to_dict()` and then store it as a string. Note this is only relevant if the CSV is not a requirement but you just want to quickly put the dataframe in an S3 bucket and retrieve it again.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import pandas as pd
import yaml

conn = S3Connection()
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucketName')
myKey = mybucket.get_key("myKeyName")

myKey.set_contents_from_string(str(df.to_dict()))
```

This will convert the df to a dict string, and then save that as json in S3. You can later read it in the same json format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(yaml.load(myKey.get_contents_as_string()))
```

The other solutions are also good, but this is a little simpler. Yaml may not necessarily be required but you need something to parse the json string. If the S3 file doesn't necessarily *need* to be a CSV this can be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import s3fs
import pandas as pd
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(profile='<profile_name>')
pd.read_csv(s3.open(<s3_path>))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.