# How to load data from your S3 bucket to Sagemaker jupyter notebook to train the model?

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have csv files in S3 bucket, I want to use those to train model in sagemaker.

using this code but it gives an error (file not found)

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
region = boto3.Session().region_name
train_data_location = 's3://taggingu-{}/train.csv'.format(region)
df=pd.read_csv(train_data_location, header = None)
print df.head
```

What can be the solution to this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load S3 Data into AWS SageMaker Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656/load-s3-data-into-aws-sagemaker-notebook)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure but could this stackoverflow answer it? [Load S3 Data into AWS SageMaker Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656)

To quote @Chhoser:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
bucket='my-bucket'
data_key = 'train.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)

pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! should have checked the previous answers, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS SDK for Pandas](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), a library that extends Pandas to work smoothly with AWS data stores.

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.s3.read_csv("s3://bucket/file.csv")
```

Most notebook kernels have it, if missing it can be installed via `pip install awswrangler`.