# Load S3 bucket Data in AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Related to the question below but I'm still struggling:

> [Load S3 Data into AWS SageMaker Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656/load-s3-data-into-aws-sagemaker-notebook)

I'm trying to load a parquet file from a local S3 bucket (it contains "sagemaker" in the name.

I'm trying to access the file using both conventions (Object URL of the file and the usually seen):

```
pf1 = ParquetFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-us-east-1-716296694085/data/t_spp_vcen_cons_sales_fact-part-1.parquet")
pf1 = ParquetFile("s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-716296694085/data/t_spp_vcen_cons_sales_fact-part-1.parquet")
df1 = pf1.to_pandas()
```

It says `FileNotFoundError` but the file is there.
The funny thing is when I create a model and use BOTO I actually am able to "write" to the same bucket:

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, np.array(train_X).astype('float32'), np.array(train_y).astype('float32'))
buf.seek(0)
key = 'linear_train.data'
prefix = "Sales_867_ts"
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_write).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train', key)).upload_fileobj(buf)
s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}/train/{}'.format(bucket_write, prefix, key)
print('uploaded training data location: {}'.format(s3_train_data))
```

So a couple of newbies questions:

- do I also need BOTO to read the file and if so - how do I do that?
- do I need somehow to amend my IAM role and do this without the "boto" command?
- when I move the data to Jupyter I actually have no issues reading it directly. Where exactly is this data stored then?

`pf1 = ParquetFile("./Sales_867_ts/inputData/t_spp_vcen_cons_sales_fact-part-1.parquet")`

Comment: Hi Bullzeye, could you post a little bit more of your code, especially your imports?  Specifically, I'd like to understand which python ParquetFile implementation you're using.  (There are a few out there.)

Answer (score 0):

just import s3fs and then df = pd.read_csv. you have to do a conda install on the s3fs library though