# How to input data from S3 Bucket to Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-s3, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker, aws-deeplens

I would like to input data(Caltech 256 dataset) from Amazon s3 to sagemaker. I am doing this because I would like to modify the dataset if I can get this to work. Any ideas?

Tried using the pandas code from 'Load S3 Data into AWS SageMaker Notebook'

I hope the data from the S3 bucket will work just like downloading straight from the url. Obviously it isn't working.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244897/6069517) may help.

Comment: You can also download the files from s3 using the "aws s3 cp" bash command from the notebook

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which part doesn't work, and what are the error messages you get?

Also note that you have your execution role configured correct for SageMaker.