# AWS S3 and Sagemaker: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have created an S3 bucket 'testshivaproject' and uploaded an image in it. When I try to access it in sagemaker notebook, it throws an error 'No such file or directory'.

```
# import libraries
import boto3, re, sys, math, json, os, sagemaker, urllib.request
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import numpy as np                                   

# Define IAM role
role = get_execution_role()

my_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name # set the region of the instance

print("success :"+my_region)
```

**Output:** success :us-east-2

```
role
```

**Output:** 'arn:aws:iam::847047967498:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20190825T121483'

```
bucket = 'testprojectshiva2' 
data_key = 'ext_image6.jpg' 
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key) 
print(data_location)
```

**Output:** s3://testprojectshiva2/ext_image6.jpg

```
test = load_img(data_location)
```

**Output:** No such file or directory

There are similar questions raised ([Load S3 Data into AWS SageMaker Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656/load-s3-data-into-aws-sagemaker-notebook)) but did not find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

I sort of guessed from your description, but are you trying to use the Keras load_img function to load images directly from your S3 bucket?

Unfortunately, [the load_img function is designed to only load files from disk](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11684), so passing an s3:// URL to that function will always return a `FileNotFoundError`.

It's common to first download images from S3 before using them, so you can use boto3 or the AWS CLI to download the file before calling load_img.

**Alternatively**, since the load_img function simply creates a [PIL Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) object, you can create the PIL object directly from the data in S3 using boto3, and not use the load_img function at all.

In other words, you could do something like this:

```py
from PIL import Image

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
test = Image.open(BytesIO(
    s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=data_key)['Body'].read()
    ))
```

Hope this helps you out in your project!

Comment: Hi Kevin. I am having a similar trouble when reading text data from a CSV file that I stored on a s3 bucket. I'm trying to use code similar to the xgboost_abalone example notebook to run predictions in a regression problem, and when using the open(FILE_DATA, 'r') line I get an error. I already checked the path and it is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code to pull in a CSV file into sagemaker.

```
import pandas as pd

bucket='your-s3-bucket'
data_key = 'your.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
df = pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

alternative formatting for data_location variable:

```
data_location = f's3://{bucket}/{data_key}'
```