# AWS Glue: Can't Examine the Schemas in the Data Catalog. No Rows in Table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I'm following an example to run a AWS Glue Job from:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html

However, I'm currently facing an issue with the 3rd step:

```
persons = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
             database="legislators",
             table_name="persons_json")
print "Count: ", persons.count()
persons.printSchema()
```

Every time I run this command I get the following output.

> Count: 0
> root

After running the Glue crawler, I managed to generate the Glue metadata tables as mentioned in Step 1
I am sure it's detecting the Glue metadata table correctly because if I change **database** parameter to something else like "legislator1", it would fail immediately which also confirms the metadata tables exists.

The above Python code was run on an AWS SageMaker notebook created under the AWS Glue service

Edit 1:
I tried to get the json file directly from the public S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME='awsglue-datasets'
KEY = 'examples/us-legislators/all/areas.json'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    obj = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, KEY)
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    print(body)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

But I get

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when
> calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

which is weird because it's supposed to be a public bucket?
I tried other ways to get the object like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060184/13126175
But it gives

> ImportError: The s3fs library is required to handle s3 files

Edit 2

I tried the same code used in Edit 1 and run it in a Glue Job to get the JSON file. It actually worked. Here's a snippet from the CloudWatch logs:

> 627\u06c1\u0648\u0645\u0627"}, {"lang": "uz", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklaxoma"}, {"lang": "vi", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "vo", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "war", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "xal", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u041e\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0445\u043e\u043c"}, {"lang": "yi", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u05d0\u05e7\u05dc\u05e2\u05d4\u05d0\u05de\u05e2"}, {"lang": "yo", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "zh", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u5967\u514b\u62c9\u8377\u99ac\u5dde"}, {"lang": "zh_hans", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u5965\u514b\u62c9\u8377\u9a6c\u5dde"}, {"lang": "ay", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma suyu"}, {"lang": "be_tarask", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0410\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0433\u043e\u043c\u0430"}, {"lang": "nb", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "pt_br", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "pa", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0a13\u0a15\u0a32\u0a3e\u0a39\u0a4b\u0a2e\u0a3e"}, {"lang": "am", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u12a6\u12ad\u120b\u1206\u121b"}, {"lang": "ne", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0913\u0915\u094d\u0932\u093e\u0939\u094b\u092e\u093e"}, {"lang": "sgs", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "yue", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u5967\u514b\u62c9\u4f55\u99ac\u5dde"}, {"lang": "nan", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "kab", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "mhr", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u041e\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0445\u043e\u043c\u043e"}, {"lang": "ce", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u041e\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0445\u043e\u043c\u0430"}, {"lang": "na", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "sc", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "te", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0c13\u0c15\u0c4d\u0c32\u0c39\u0c4b\u0c2e\u0c3e"}, {"lang": "sah", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u041e\u043a\u043b\u0430h\u043e\u043c\u0430"}, {"lang": "mzn", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0627\u0648\u06a9\u0644\u0627\u0647\u0627\u0645\u0627"}, {"lang": "pi", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0913\u0915\u094d\u0932\u093e\u0939\u094b\u092e\u093e"}, {"lang": "cdo", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"lang": "bxr", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u041e\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0445\u043e\u043c\u0430"}, {"lang": "azb", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0627\u0648\u06a9\u0644\u0627\u0647\u0645\u0627 \u0627\u06cc\u0627\u0644\u062a\u06cc"}, {"lang": "bho", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u0913\u0915\u094d\u0932\u093e\u0939\u094b\u092e\u093e"}, {"lang": "xmf", "note": "multilingual", "name": "\u10dd\u10d9\u10da\u10d0\u10f0\u10dd\u10db\u10d0"}, {"lang": "de_ch", "note": "multilingual", "name": "Oklahoma"}, {"la

I don't think it's permission issues because I already gave my notebook Admin access for testing purposes.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are able to access the public s3 bucket from sagemaker notebook ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I tried and updated in my edit above.

Comment: Can you try running this code and boto3 snippet as a Glue job which can rule out that issues only happening with sagemaker?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Thanks for your suggestion. Oddly enough, it actually worked if I run it as a Glue job. See my Edit 2