# Loading data from S3 bucket to SageMaker Jupyter Notebook - ValueError - Invalid bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

following the answers to this question [Load S3 Data into AWS SageMaker Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656/load-s3-data-into-aws-sagemaker-notebook) I tried to load data from S3 bucket to SageMaker Jupyter Notebook.

I used this code:

```
import pandas as pd

bucket='my-bucket'
data_key = 'train.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)

pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

I replaced `'my-bucket'` by the ARN (Amazon Ressource name) of my S3 bucket (e.g. "`arn:aws:s3:::name-of-bucket`") and replaced `'train.csv'` by the csv-filename which is stored in the S3 bucket. Regarding the rest I did not change anything at all. What I got was this `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Failed to head path 'arn:aws:s3:::name-of-bucket/name_of_file_V1.csv': Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-bucket": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

What did I do wrong? Do I have to modify the name of my S3 bucket?

Comment: I found it: I just had to replace `my-bucket` by `name-of-bucket` without the complete ARN, so without `arn:aws:s3:::`. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path should be:

```
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
```

where `bucket` is `<bucket-name>` **not ARN**. For example `bucket=my-bucket-333222`.

Comment: Does each sagemaker session has its own default bucket or all sessions share same default bucket? Also if later is true, then  do all notebook instances have same default bucket?