# How can I retrieve a folder from S3 into an AWS SageMaker notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a folder with several files corresponding to checkpoints of a RL model trained using RLLIB. I want to make an analysis of the checkpoints in a way that I need to pass a certain folder as an argument, e.g., `analysis_function(folder_path)`. I have to run this line on a SageMaker notebook. I have seen that there are some questions on SO about how to retrieve files from s3, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264656/load-s3-data-into-aws-sagemaker-notebook) one. However; how can I retrieve a whole folder?

Answer (score 0):

To read the whole folder, you will just have to list all files in the folder and loop through them. You could either do something like -

```
import boto3
s3_res = boto3.resource("s3")
my_bucket = s3.Bucket("<your-bucket-name>")

for object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="<your-prefix>")
    # your code goes here
```

Or, simply download the files to your local storage and loop them as you see fit ([copy reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html))-

`!aws s3 cp s3://bucket/prefix/ . --recursive`