# Read excel file from S3 into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a SNS notification setup that triggers a Lambda function when a .xlsx file is uploaded to S3 bucket.

The lambda function reads the .xlsx file into Pandas DataFrame.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
import json
import xlrd
import boto3

def main(event, context):
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    parsed_message = json.loads(message)
    src_bucket = parsed_message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    filepath = parsed_message['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=src_bucket, Key=filepath)
    print(obj['Body'])

    df = pd.read_excel(obj, header=2)
    print(df.head(2))
```

I get an error as below:

```
Invalid file path or buffer object type: <type 'dict'>: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/handler.py", line 26, in main
df = pd.read_excel(obj, header=2)
File "/var/task/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/task/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel.py", line 307, in read_excel
io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel.py", line 376, in __init__
io, _, _, _ = get_filepath_or_buffer(self._io)
File "/var/task/pandas/io/common.py", line 218, in get_filepath_or_buffer
raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <type 'dict'>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly normal! obj is a dictionnary, have u tried ?

```
df = pd.read_excel(obj['body'], header=2)
```

Comment: That was it. df = pd.read_excel(obj['body'], header=2). Your post is missing closing ] for 'body'. Thank you for the help.

Comment: My pleasure :) 
P.S: I have added the ]

Answer (score 4):

try `pd.read_excel(obj['Body'].read())`

Answer (score 2):

Pandas now supports s3 URL as a file path so it can read the excel file directly from s3 without downloading it first.

See here for a CSV example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777553/52954

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is a dictionary, you could try

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(obj)
```

[Documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) if you need to change params.