# Pandas pd.read_csv(s3_path) fails with "TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-emr, coroutine, python-s3fs

I am running a spark application in Amazon EMR Cluster and since a few days ago, I am getting the following error whenever I try reading a file from S3 using pandas. I have added bootstrap actions to install pandas, fsspec and s3fs.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(s3_path)
```

**Error Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark.py", line 84, in <module>
    df=pd.read_csv('s3://<bucketname>/<filename>.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 222, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    filepath_or_buffer, mode=mode or "rb", **(storage_options or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 133, in open
    out = self.__enter__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 101, in __enter__
    f = self.fs.open(self.path, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 844, in open
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 394, in _open
    autocommit=autocommit, requester_pays=requester_pays)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1276, in __init__
    cache_type=cache_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1134, in __init__
    self.details = fs.info(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 719, in info
    return sync(self.loop, self._info, path, bucket, key, kwargs, version_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 51, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 35, in f
    result[0] = await future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 660, in _info
    Key=key, **version_id_kw(version_id), **self.req_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 214, in _call_s3
    raise translate_boto_error(err)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 207, in _call_s3
    return await method(**additional_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 121, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 140, in _make_request
    return await self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 90, in _send_request
    exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 199, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/hooks.py", line 29, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 1225, in redirect_from_error
    new_region = self.get_bucket_region(bucket, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 1283, in get_bucket_region
    headers = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AioBaseClient._make_api_call' was never awaited
```

Could there be an issue with the [s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/#history) as this and pandas seems to be the only packages that received updates, but I couldn't find anything in the pandas' changelogs related to this?

Comment: refer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703634/how-to-import-a-text-file-on-aws-s3-into-pandas-without-writing-to-disk

Comment: @PrateekSohlot that was from the previous versions of pandas when it used boto. Now it uses s3fs to read files from buckets. I know we can read using boto3 as well, but why write extra lines of code when something is natively supported? All I am looking for is what caused these recent issues.

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior with pandas on recent versions. I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dask/s3fs](https://github.com/dask/s3fs) team has acknowledged this to be a bug. This [Github issue](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/issues/350#issuecomment-682570558) suggests that the [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore/issues/825) is unable to get the **region_name** for the S3 bucket.

If you are facing the same issue, either consider downgrading s3fs to `0.4.2` or else try setting the environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` as a workaround.

Edit: It has been fixed in the latest release of `aiobotocore=1.1.1`. Upgrade your aiobotocore and s3fs if you are facing the same issue.

Comment: Great, thankyou for sharing as an answer, i deleted my Answer.