# S3 to Pandas with local variable authentication

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, python-s3fs

I'm downloading a file (to be precise a parquet set of files) from S3 and converting that to a Pandas `DataFrame`. I'm doing that with the Pandas function `read_parquet` and `s3fs`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777553/3076438):

```
df = pd.read_parquet(f's3://{bucket}/{path}')
```

However, I could only do that so far if I authenticate via environment variable or AWS config file. Because of company standards I would like instead to authenticate via local variables, such as the way we do with `pyarrow.parquet`:

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secret=config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
df = pq.ParquetDataset(f's3://{bucket}/{path}', filesystem=fs).read().to_pandas()
```

Is there a way to do that with `read_parquet`? Can't I use something like a `filesystem` argument with it?

In case anyone is curious, I'm not using `pq.ParquetDataset` because it is too slow (I have no idea why).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass a file-like object to `pandas.read_parquet`:

```
with fs.open(f's3://{bucket}/{path}') as fp:
  pq.read_parquet(fp)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, `KeyError: 'ETag'`, do you know what that's about?