# Receiving TypeError, when PandasCursor is imported from pyathena.pandas.cursor

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyathena

I want to read an excel file into `pandas` from an AWS S3 bucket. Everything worked fine But when I import `PandasCursor`, which I need for another part of the code, I receive the following error message:

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs
from pyathena import connect
from pyathena.pandas.cursor import PandasCursor

path = "s3://some/path/to/file.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(path)

>>>TypeError: S3FileSystem.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'connection'
```

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can fix it?
From the [pyathena docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/#pandascursor) I don't understand how `PandasCursor` is influencing `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: Use the AWS pandas SDK library https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_excel.html. or check the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703634/how-to-import-a-text-file-on-aws-s3-into-pandas-without-writing-to-disk/51777553#51777553

Comment: the answer you suggested is exactly what I've tried. I edited my question to include the s3fs import

Comment: Have you also setup the aws profile correctly,  can you try 'aws s3 ls ' from command prompt and verify if the access is proper

Comment: I used `aws-azure-login` for authentication: https://github.com/aws-azure-login/aws-azure-login. `aws s3 ls` leads to `-bash: aws: command not found`

Comment: @VikramS: I followed theses Instructions to install AWS CLI but the error still occurs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Comment: your suggestion to use awswrangler works, thanks for that. I still don't understand, why my approach doesn't