# Trouble reading csvs saved in sharefile (citrix)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sharefile

I wrote the following code to create dataframes from files saved in sharefile. It works perfectly for excel files, but fails for csv files with the error *EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file*.

```
tblname = 'test'
fPth = r'Z:\Favorites\test10 (Group D - Custom EM&V)\8 PII\16 - Project Selection Plan\QC\Data\test.csv'
sht = 'Gross_Data'
shtStart = 0
fType = 'csv'
fitem = sfsession.get_io_version(fPth)

if fitem is None:
    print(f'Could not create sharefile item for {fPth}')
else: 
    try:
        if fType == 'csv':
            df = pd.read_csv(fitem.io_data, header = shtStart)
        elif fType == 'excel':
            df = pd.read_excel(fitem.io_data, sheet_name = sht, header = shtStart)
        else:
            pass
        print(f'Data import COMPLETE for {fPth}: {str(datetime.now())}')
    except:
        print(f'Data import FAILED for {fPth}')
        logging.critical(f'Data import FAILED for {fPth}')
```

If I replace *fitem.io_data* with *fPth* in *df = pd.read_csv*, the code works, but I can't use that as a permanent solution. Any suggestions?

Also sfsession is a sharefile session and get_io_version(fPth) gets the token and downloads all the file properties include its data. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation of this solution worked for me: 
[StringIO and pandas read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447448/stringio-and-pandas-read-cs)

I added *fitem.io_data.seek(0)* before the *df = ...* line

Closing the question.